# asp.net upload image to data base?

Tags: asp.net

Just wanna ask what is the code to upload image to database is it the same as inserting values in table data?can you give me example codes how to upload image to database?A friend of mine said i should use XML for my image upload.

Comment: well if you ask me none... of the upload or xml

Comment: my advice store your image on the directory create a folder for images and store the image path in your database.

Comment: Why should you store image in database.Just store your image name just like other data and upload your image in any folder.When you try to get image call the image name from database and give a proper path to fetch a image.

Comment: im still learning :/ is it a bit advance for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

advice : do *not* store image on db.

store their path.

*now , for your question :*

you should convert the image into byte array : 
something like :

```
File.GetAllBytes("readme.jpg")
```

now , in the sql (server i assume , ) make a varbinary column

and just pass the byte array into this column.

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Save files into SQL Server Database using File Uploader Control
http://ajaxuploader.com/h/Save-Files-to-Database-using-FileUpload-Control.htm

A sample demonstrates how to use File Uploader Control to upload multiple files to the database asynchronously. Users can select multiple files to upload by using the SHIFT key or CTRL key when selecting files on the file upload dialog.

> > advice : do not store image on db.

Uploading files is a common activity in Asp.net application, in general we upload the files and save them to the file system and store the URL of the saved file in the database, but there are specific scenarios which demand us to store the entire files into the database in binary format.